# Search for all strings from input.file on all files in target-directory(ies)/ and print (Bash)

Tags: bash, recursion, input, grep, find

I need to search all files in a target directory and print all matching found strings from input file. Can't seem to be able to do that. Below an example scenario and the problem:

```
$ tree .
.
├── input_file.txt
└── target-dir
    ├── target-file-A.txt
    ├── target-file-B.txt
    ├── target-subdir-A
    │   ├── target-file-A.txt
    │   └── target-file-B.txt
    └── target-subdir-B
        ├── target-file-A.txt
        └── target-file-B.txt

$ cat input_file.txt
abc
cba
bca
acb

$ cat target-dir/target-file-A.txt
abc
cba
bca
acb
$ cat target-dir/target-file-B.txt
acb
cba
abc
bca
0101
1010

$ grep -f input_file.txt -r .

./input_file.txt:acb

./target-dir/target-file-A.txt:acb
./target-dir/target-file-B.txt:acb

./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-A.txt:acb
./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-B.txt:acb

./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-A.txt:acb
./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-B.txt:acb
```

I see only one matching line printed (first) and rest is ignored. How can I get all matching lines printed?
I need to search through tons of network logs for all hits to IOC (IP/URL) and this proves harder than anticipated.
**EDIT:** I should mention this is "Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS \n \l" working under Windows 10 as **WSL**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grep command:

```
grep -f input_file.txt -r .
```

should work as You are expecting and match all strings in input_file.txt separated by new lines in all files under `./`. It that case am I suspicious files having Windows end lines having been created under Windows. You can try following to make sure You have proper UNIX end lines:

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

And try again.

Comment: Thank you - this was exactly the case. I just came to the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't kill me. Maybe somebody will find this post useful anyway.

The solution is: LINE ENCODING.
Since I natively run on Windows my Sublime Text is set to "Windows Line Endings" while WSL is Unix, thus doesn't understand those line endings. After switching the option in the editor everything works fine:

```
$ cat -A input_file_changed.txt
abc$
cba$
bca$
acb

$ cat -A input_file.txt
abc^M$
cba^M$
bca^M$
acb

    $ grep -f input_file_changed.txt -r .
    ./input_file.txt:abc
    ./input_file.txt:cba
    ./input_file.txt:bca
    ./input_file.txt:acb
    ./input_file_changed.txt:abc
    ./input_file_changed.txt:cba
    ./input_file_changed.txt:bca
    ./input_file_changed.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-file-A.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-file-A.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-file-A.txt:bca
    ./target-dir/target-file-A.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-file-B.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-file-B.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-file-B.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-file-B.txt:bca
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-A.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-A.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-A.txt:bca
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-A.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-B.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-B.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-B.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-A/target-file-B.txt:bca
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-A.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-A.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-A.txt:bca
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-A.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-B.txt:acb
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-B.txt:cba
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-B.txt:abc
    ./target-dir/target-subdir-B/target-file-B.txt:bca
```